# How to minimize distance between cities in Gurobi?

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to build a model using Gurobi but having trouble with the syntax.

I have a list of distances and cities. dist is the distance between each city. For example, Chicago to Chicago would be 0 then Chicago to Boston is 443, Chicago to DC is 223, and so on. There are len(city)*len(city) variables in the dist list.

```
dist = [0,443,223,123,124,778,123,0,344,455,412,1235...]
city = ["Chicago","Boston","D.C.","Seattle","Los Angeles","Raleigh"]
```

So, now I set a decision variable to

```
store = m.addVars(city, city, obj = Distances, name = "store")
print(store)
<Chicago, Chicago> <Chicago, Boston> <Chicago, D.C.> ... 
<Raleigh, Chicago> <Raleigh, Boston>, <Raleigh, D.C.>... <Raleigh, Raleigh>
```

How would I set my constraints and objective so that it looks for the lowest distances between each city.

Comment: Are you looking for help with the mathematical model or for coding a specific model with Gurobi?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the all-pairs shortest path problem. This problem can be solved with specialized algorithms that are not too complicated (see [link](https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/09-apsp.pdf)). I don't think there is a compact formulation as LP/MIP.